# Why function is not returning negative value in C?

Tags: c

I am writing this code to return a value which I will pass through the parameter of the function and print that value.
here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int abs(int x)
{
    if(x<0)
       return x;
}
int main()
{
    int x = -6;
    printf("Value of abs is %d\n",abs(x));
   return 0;
}
```

This code giving me the output:

> Value of abs is 6

*Why this code is not returning -6  ?*

how to solve this ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: This function will cause undefined behavior if `x >= 0`. Also, is this the exact code?

Comment: "Not all paths return a value"

Comment: Yes this is the exact code. I need to print -6

Comment: It *does* print `-6`. The problem is with positive numbers.

Comment: @shuvro Try renaming the function to something else as to not collide with the existing `abs` (which would return 6)

Comment: Interestingly, for me clang prints -6 at -O0 and 6 at -O1.

Comment: Should stdlib.h not be needed for the inbuilt abs()?

Comment: @MartinJames There is a difference between compilation and linking. When the program is linked the built-in `abs()` will be used. *stdlib.h* only provides a declaration for `abs()` which you can manually add without including it `int abs(int);` is enough.

Comment: @iharob orite, yes, of course!  Thanks for correcting me:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the function, the compiler is using the *built-in* `abs()` function instead of the one you defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Abs(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
       return x;
    return -x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = -6;
    printf("Value of abs is %d\n", Abs(x));
    return 0;
}
```

The *gcc* compiler has an option for this, `-fno-builtin` would respect every conflicting user defined function, if you just want to override 1 use `-fno-builtin-abs` in the case it's `abs()`.

Comment: I wonder why there is no redefinition-warning or the builtin function is not overwritten by the explicit definition.